# UnsatisfiedLinkError while using speex codec library in android

Tags: java, android, codec, speex

I am completely newbie to this topic .I want to use speex codec in my application for that I have followed this [link to include speex lib in android app](http://developer.samsung.com/android/technical-docs/Porting-and-Using-the-Speex-Library-in-Android-with-JNI).I have completed all the steps [getting all c files and compiling them using NDK ] and have run this code lines

```
static {
    System.loadLibrary("speex");
}
private native void initEncoder(int mode, int quality);
private native void destroyEncoder();
private native int encodeFile(String sourcePath, String targetPath);

@
Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    initEncoder(AudioManager.ADJUST_RAISE, 5);
    File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/encoded_file");
    encodeFile(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/06-Jab Tak Hai Jaan[MusikMaza.Com].mp3", f.getAbsolutePath());
    destroyEncoder();
}
```

and got this error

```
11-06 16:21:12.620: E/AndroidRuntime(32612): Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load speex: find Library returned null.
```

I seems library is not getting loaded by error name .So please tell me how to resolve this.Any kind of suggestion/help will be appreciated.Thanks in advance

Comment: have u generate .so file in your application dear

Comment: where do you have your *.so libs : \libs\armeabi\
   libs\armeabi-v7a\  ?

Comment: try to put your .so lib in libs\armeabi-v7a  instead of  \libs\armeabi

Comment: @BhanuSharma : I have libs-->armeabi where armeabi is empty and obj->local->armeabi->objs->libspeex.so

Comment: no no no dear have u use "Cygwin64 Terminal" to compile then automatically generate .so file

Comment: @BhanuSharma I have compiled using ndk as mentioned in that link.Is that wrong?

Comment: i know dear and i completed this but u have to compile with this tool :)

Comment: from where u belong and in which company

Comment: @BhanuSharma one more question .Should armeabi folder inside libs folder be remain  empty??

Comment: @BhanuSharma sir I have read about cygwin this tool is for windows to get linux environment but I am already developing app on linux in fedora os